# typescript Json : adding child items

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

Hi i am new to json and typescript.
I need to process below json object where i need to process below json for its each childValues and then set the attributes of parentValues to the sum of corresponding attributes of its child.

```
 "parentValues":[{
 "number1": 0,
 "number2": 0,
 "parentId": 1,
 "childValues": [{
         "number1": 10,
         "number2": 20,
         "childId": 1
     },
     {
         "number1": 30,
         "number2": 40,
         "childId": 2
     }
 ]}]
```

This needs to be converted into following :

```
"parentValues":[{
 "number1": 10+30,
 "number2": 20+40,
 "parentId": 1,
 "childValues": [{
         "number1": 10,
         "number2": 20,
         "childId": 1
     },
     {
         "number1": 30,
         "number2": 40,
         "childId": 2
     }
 ]}]
```

Comment: Please include what you have so far and explain where you are having trouble. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0):

Solution is following, lets assume we have array `parentValues` of objects:

```
let parentValues = [{
 "number1": 0,
 "number2": 0,
 "parentId": 1,
 "childValues": [{
         "number1": 10,
         "number2": 20,
         "childId": 1
     },
     {
         "number1": 30,
         "number2": 40,
         "childId": 2
     }
 ]}];


for(let i = 0; i < parentValues.length; i++ ) {
   for(let j = 0; j < parentValues[i]["childValues"].length; j++) {
       parentValues[i].number1 = parentValues[i]["childValues"][j].number1;
       parentValues[i].number2 = parentValues[i]["childValues"][j].number2;
   }
}
```

No matter on witch language you do this, important is logic.

This solutions a bit awful and can be improved and can be concise, but works :)